# Swipebox - Issue when playing a youtube video and navigating to another video in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-plugins, youtube

The following only occurs in a newly release Chrome browser (meaning it was working on a previous Chrome browser version) while using the JQuery plugin [Swipebox](https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox). Firefox, IE and Edge all work as expected.

Issue (swipebox 1.4.1 latest):
While playing a Youtube Video, click swipebox's Next or Prev navigation arrows.
The next video will be showed, however, trying to play this video will result in the next video to appear on top of the current video, which is actually playing (you can hear the sound, but can not see it).
The close "X" and navigation arrows are no longer visible.
You are now stuck. Must refresh page or press "ESC".

Again, in IE, Firefox and Edge, the video navigation all behave properly.
This only seems to occur on the Chrome browser.

**How to replicate:**
Example video page: http://donsfootwear.com/production-videos

1. Click a thumbnail - The Swipebox plugin will initiate and show the video preview fullscreen.
2. Play video by clicking on it - The video will start playing.
3. Whist the video plays, click the "Next" arrow - The next video preview will be showed.
4. Play video by clicking on it.
5. You are now stuck - The video you just clicked play will disappear. The next video preview will be shown (unresponsive).  Swipebox "X" close and "Next"/"Prev" navigation buttons will disappear. Only way to escape is pressing "ESC" or refresh page.

Anyone can verify/experienced this with their own site, and most importantly have a workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed via a google chrome update recently.